# How to forward openvpn/wireguard to another wirdguard interface without modifying global route table?

Tags: routing, openvpn, iptables, nat, wireguard

I have one wireguard interface wg_vpn， but I don't want it to be global, so I add the line "Table = off" to the wg_vpn.conf to prevent wg-quick to modify the route table.

I also have an openvpn/wireguard interface tun0/wg0, and the clients can access my server through it. I've created these iptables rules:

```
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg_vpn  -j MASQUERADE
    iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o wg_vpn -j ACCEPT
    
    ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg_vpn  -j MASQUERADE
    ip6tables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o wg_vpn -j ACCEPT
```

But they don't work, unless I make wg_vpn global by:

```
    ip route add default dev wg_vpn
    ip -6 route add default dev wg_vpn
```

Then they work.

But I just want to forward tun0/wg0 to wg_vpn without modify global route table, so may I know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *policy routing* with `ip rule`.

1. Instead of `Table=off`, specify `Table=123` to make wg-quick place the routes in a separate table (any 16-bit number except 253–255, which are the global tables).

   ...or manually add your routes to a new table:

   ```
   ip -4 route add default dev wg_vpn table 123
   ip -6 route add default dev wg_vpn table 123
   ```
2. Create policy routing rules to select this table for packets received from tun0:

   ```
   ip -4 rule add pref 1000 iif tun0 lookup 123
   ip -6 rule add pref 1000 iif tun0 lookup 123
   ```